# Return also empty matches from SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select

I use this SQL query to get data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM common.ACTIVE_PAIRS ap 
INNER JOIN exchanges ON exchanges.exchange_id = ap.exchange_id 
ORDER BY :sort 
LIMIT :limit 
OFFSET :offset
```

The issue is that sometimes `ap.exchange_id` can be empty and I don't have a row.
Do you know how I can return the result with empty `ap.exchange_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what outer (or left) joins are for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM common.ACTIVE_PAIRS ap 
LEFT JOIN exchanges ON exchanges.exchange_id = ap.exchange_id -- Note the left join
ORDER BY :sort 
LIMIT :limit 
OFFSET :offset
```